# How to load multiple values from a field with views_php module?

Tags: 7, views, entities, media

I'm trying to build a responsive gallery. Since views won't let me rewrite the field's output with html5 data attributes I need to print the output using a PHP field in views.

Using the module [views_php](http://drupal.org/project/views_php), I'm accessing the values of the image field this way:

```
$source = $data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->my_field['und'][0]['filename'];
```

This way I load the value from the ['und'][0] array, this would work properly if a field  has a single value.
But what if in the node creation, in my field I want to upload multiple images. How could I change the [und] numerical value to load as many values as my field has.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should try a foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Syd said, it seems like you need a foreach loop. It's not readily apparent what you're wanting to do with the `$source` variable, but I'm guessing it's something like the following:

```
foreach ($data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->my_field['und'] as $a_file) {
    echo '<img src="' . $a_file['filename'] . '">';
}
```